# Rxjs conditional diverging paths inside pipe, and then converge branching paths?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, conditional-statements

New to rxjs and getting stumped by conditional pipe flows.

I've currently got a flow that looks something like this

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myRootService.getRoot().pipe(
        map((root: Root) => {
            return this.mySecondService.getOtherData(root);
        }),
        switchMap((otherData: OtherDataType) => {
            return this.convertToUsableData(otherData);
        })
    ).subscribe((data: UsableDataType) => {
        this.use(data);
    });
}
```

However, there's a chance I can avoid that second service call if I already have the data I need on hand. That would be a flow that looks like this

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myRootService.getRoot().pipe(
        map((root: Root) => {
        //we have data already
            return this.getUsableData(root);
        })
    ).subscribe((data: UsableDataType) => {
        this.use(data);
    });
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can conditionally branch multiple pipe steps and then reconverge later on. Depending on whether I have the data or not, I'll be dealing with different data types at different stages. I'd love if I could have certain parts of it be conditional, but my own research on conditionals in rxjs has me confused.

Of course I could just check `this.getUsableData()` and then wrap the two separate flows in a traditional if-else based on the response, but I wonder if there's a way I can do this intelligently inside the pipe. Would love if I could bracket off parts of the pipeline somehow. Something like this, except good:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myRootService.getRoot().pipe(
        map((root: Root) => {
            return (this.getData(root) || this.mySecondService.getOtherData(root)
                .pipe(
                    map((otherData: OtherDataType) =>
                        this.convertToData(otherData)
                    )
                ));
        })
    ).subscribe((data: UsableDataType) => {
        this.use(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the names of the functions? Sometimes its `getData()` and other times `getUsableData()` or `convertToUsableData()` and `convertToData()`. Are these all seperate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, sometimes you have the data, so you don't need subscribe to an additional observable. But other times, it's necessary to subscribe to another observable.

To make this work, you can just fabricate an observable from your already existing data using `of()` when the data is already present:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myRootService.getRoot().pipe(
        switchMap(root => {
            const existingData = this.getData(root);

            return existingData
                ? of(existingData)
                : this.mySecondService.getOtherData(root).pipe(
                    map(otherData => this.convertToData(otherData))
                  )
        })
    ).subscribe((data: UsableDataType) => {
        this.use(data);
    });
}
```